# Route Query Lost After Page Refresh [nextjs]

Tags: react-router, next.js

I'm using a route query to pass a product ID through to my product page, allowing me to pull all of the related info in getInitialProps.

This works well until the page is refreshed, when the page is refreshed the query id is lost and the product info can no longer be pulled.

Is there a way to persist the query after refresh?

Thanks

Comment: You should also send the query to your adress bar too. For example: `localhost:3000/posts?page=2`

Comment: That will do it. Thanks.